# Which way of saying is more general?

Tags: nouns, possessive-adjectives

Consider the following two sentences, where I highlighted the differences between them:

- Technology has drastically improved the easy of obtaining information: from making **a phone call** in **the forests** and get the most recent progress of **your** business, to accessing in-flight internet and not lose track of what is happening in the stock **market**.
- Technology has drastically improved the easy of obtaining information: from making **phone calls** in **the forest** and get the most recent progress of **one's** business, to accessing in-flight internet and not lose track of what is happening in the stock **markets**.

My question is:

1. Are both sentences correct grammatically?
2. Do they have the same meaning? If not, what are the differences?
3. Which expressions in each sentence is more general?

Comment: The highlighted sections are not really where the main issues lie; but I don't see this as anything other than a proofreading request.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. Probably! Since I might have accidentally made other mistakes in the sentences, please correct me if possible!

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - we don't do proofreading requests. "Please don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site:

Proofreading (for example, "Are there any mistakes?" or "Is this correct?"), unless a source of concern is clearly specified"

Comment: @DoneWithThis. Could you instead answer my questions eventhough the sentences are incorrect somewhere else (but the meanings are still clear)?

Comment: @DoneWithThis Notice that the on-topic rule says **"unless a source of concern is clearly specified"**.   In this case, OP clearly does specify their sources of concern, by using boldface to highlight the parts of the sentence they think may be problematic.

Comment: @BadZen - the OP gives us two broad sets of alternatives & asks us to choose, with no explanation, then asks three separate questions about them. That is a not 'clearly specified'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(context: I am a native speaker of American English)

### First, a few grammatical changes:

Technology has drastically improved the **ease** of obtaining information: from making a phone call in the forests and **getting** the most recent progress of your business, to accessing in-flight internet and not **losing** track of what is happening in the stock market.

- Easy is an adjective. Ease is a noun or a verb. You cannot have "the easy" instead you'd say "the ease."
- Your examples are all gerunds and need the -ing ending. You do this correctly with the words "making" and "accessing" but need to add *ing* to "get" and "lose."

### Phone Calls in a Forest

*"making a phone call in the forests"* vs *"making phone calls in the forest"*
I feel that the meaning here is basically identical in your context, and it is clear what you are trying to say. I would write:

*making phone calls in a forest* to be the most general.

You aren't talking about just one phone call, you're talking about any number of phone calls, so using the plural makes more sense to me. And then using the definite article "the" in front of forest has has a small implication that there might be a specific forest. Using "a" instead makes it a little bit more general.

### Your vs One

*"getting the most recent progress of your business"* vs *"getting the most recent progress of one's business"*
This is a question of formality. In formal written English, typically the audience is not addressed directly, so using a 3rd person pronoun like "one" or "he/she" or "they" would be most formal. In less formal English, it's acceptable to use the 2nd person pronoun "you" instead.

I'm not sure what the context is. In American English, the formal "one's business" would be appropriate for legal writing or for a very formal business setting. "Your business" could be used anywhere else, in writing or speaking, in a school setting, or in most workplaces.

### Stock Market vs Stock Markets

*"in the stock market"* vs *"in the stock markets"* In American English, the stock market is a collective noun that does not have a plural form, so it would just be "stock market" singular. I am not sure if this is the same in other dialects though.

Comment: In your answer, when you said you would write "Making phone calls in a forest" to be the most general, is it also equally general to write "Making phone calls in forests", using the plural form of 'forest'?

Comment: @ASlowLearner Yep! That also works.

Answer (score 0):

These sentences need improvement.  There are some diction problems, agreement problems, and you should modify the structure so that it is parallel.

Instead, you might write:

**Technology has drastically improved the ease of obtaining information. Now, even if you are in a forest or on an airplane mid-flight, you can make phone calls, check up on your business, access the Internet, or stay connected to the stock market.**

Notice that the sentence was broken up to avoid a run-on, agrees in time and number, now uses "ease" instead of "easy", and has a "things you can do" list which is properly parallel.

A reader would likely understand your two sentences as well as this one to all mean the same thing, but this one is grammatical and sounds natural.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: [DO NOT FEED THE BEARS](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/do-not-feed-the-bears) and [Stop answering close-worthy questions!](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/stop-answering-close-worthy-questions)

Comment: @BadZen In your revised sentence, can I use the plural forms of forest and airplane? i.e., "...Now even if you are in forests or on airplanes mid-flight, you can make phone calls..."?

Comment: No, it sounds like the person is more then one airplane or more than one forest at a time, which is impossible.